# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mask-rcnn

This is my code

```
import os
import cv2
from mrcnn.config import Config  # Import the Config class
from mrcnn import model as modellib
from mrcnn import utils

# Define configuration parameters
class MyConfig(Config):
    NAME = "my_config"
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1
    DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.9
    IMAGE_MAX_DIM = 1024  # Adjust this value based on your requirements

# Rest of your code...


# Load the dataset
dataset_dir = "output/histogram_equalization"
image_subdirs = os.listdir(dataset_dir)

# Create a list of image paths and corresponding class IDs
image_paths = []
class_ids = []

for image_subdir in image_subdirs:
    image_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, image_subdir)
    for image_filename in os.listdir(image_dir):
        image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, image_filename)
        image_paths.append(image_path)
        class_ids.append(int(image_subdir))

# Load and preprocess images
images = []
for image_path in image_paths:
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (MyConfig.IMAGE_MAX_DIM, MyConfig.IMAGE_MAX_DIM))
    images.append(image)

# Generate bounding boxes and masks
bboxes = []
masks = []

for image_id in range(len(images)):
    class_id = class_ids[image_id]
    bbox = utils.generate_bbox(images[image_id], class_id)
    masks.append(utils.generate_mask_for_bbox(images[image_id], bbox))
    bboxes.append(bbox)

# Convert data into a format suitable for Mask R-CNN training
dataset = {
    "images": images,
    "class_ids": class_ids,
    "bboxes": bboxes,
    "masks": masks
}

# Train the Mask R-CNN model
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(config=MyConfig(), model_dir="./")
# model.load_weights("mask_rcnn_weights.h5", by_name=True)  # Load pre-trained weights if available
model.train(dataset, dataset, epochs=20, layers="all")  # Adjust layers based on your needs

# Save the trained model
model.keras_model.save("mask_rcnn_model.h5")
```

I install tensorflow and keras and all dependencce but all time show

```
C:\Users\mhlim\OneDrive\Desktop\Image_processing\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\mhlim\OneDrive\Desktop\Image_processing\RCNN.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mhlim\OneDrive\Desktop\Image_processing\RCNN.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mrcnn import model as modellib
  File "C:\Users\mhlim\OneDrive\Desktop\Image_processing\venv\Lib\site-packages\mrcnn\model.py", line 24, in <module>
    import keras.engine as KE
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine'
```

Comment: Most likely you have wrong versions installed. The repository is very outdated, last updated in 2019. [See here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN#requirements)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your environment is python 3+ version.

uninstall the packages and freshly install using pip, also update pip version.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade tensorflow keras mrcnn
```

try the following too

```
!pip uninstall keras-nightly
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow
!pip install h5py==2.10.0
!pip install tensorflow==1.15
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
!pip install keras==2.1.6
```